# Convention d'Accueil

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen-visas, working-visas, new-caledonia

I have been offered a scientific research position (PostDoc) at Institut de recherche pour le développement (IRD) in New Caledonia for 1 year. I would like to apply for 'Long Stay Visa for Scientific-Researcher'. There is a required document "Convention d'Accueil" for the visa application. Does anyone know how to get this document?

At the moment, I have a document of working contract signed by the head of the Institute (IRD). Is this document mean the "Convention d'Accueil"?

Can anyone explain to me for this?

Comment: It's possible that you have to apply for a work visa instead.

Comment: Hello user67018, perhaps you should ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange. One year stay is more their area of expertise.

Comment: There's a description in English [here](http://www.upmc.fr/en/international/mobility_for_professor_researchers/convention_d_accueil.html).